# Using Recursion to raise a base to its exponent - C++

Tags: c++, recursion, pow

I simply want to write some code that makes use of recursion of functions to raise a base to its power. I know that recursion is not the most right way to do things in C++, but I just want to explore the concept a bit. The program asks the user for a base and an exponent and then console outs the answer. Here's the program I've written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int raisingTo(int, int);
int main()
{
    int base, exponent;
    cout << "Enter base value: ";
    cin >> base;
    cout << "Enter exponent value: ";
    cin >> exponent;
    int answer = raisingTo(base, exponent);
    cout << "The answer is: " << answer << endl;
    char response;
    cin >> response;
    return 0;
}

int raisingTo(int base, int exponent)
{
    if (exponent > 0)
        return 1;
    else if (exponent = 0)
    {
        int answer = (int) pow((double)base, raisingTo(base, (exponent - 1)));
        return answer;
    }
}
```

The funny thing is, when I run this program, it keeps returning the answer as '1'! Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int raisingTo(int base, unsigned int exponent)
{
    if (exponent == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return base * raisingTo(base, exponent - 1);
}
```

You have 3 main problems:

- You don't have to use pow function
- To compare number you should use `==` as `=` is an assignment not compare.
- You missed that if exponent is equal 0 you should return 1.

Comment: Could you please explain how each of the values are returned and how they accumulate? Could you also tell me why you've multiplied the base with the raisingTo() function? I'm only a beginner and I really don't understand the references I find online!

Comment: We use the equation: x^n = x * x^(n-1) which is true for all real numbers. So that we use it to create recursive function. The bottom of recursion is when the exponent == 0. For example `2^4 = 2 * 2^3`; `2^3 = 2 * 2^2`; `2^2 = 2 * 2^1`; `2^1 = 2 * 2^0` and `2^0 = 1`.

Answer (score 2):

To make this an actual C++ answer – this is the kind of task where you might consider making it a template function, as this should work with any kind of number type.

Recursion *is* in fact a good idea, but only if you make use of the benefits it can offer: it can avoid some of the multiplications, by factoring out low numbers from the exponent.

```
template <typename NumT>
NumT raiseTo(NumT base, unsigned exponent) {
  if (exponent == 1) return base;
  if (exponent == 0) return 1;
  if (exponent%2 == 0) { NumT ressqrt = raiseTo(base,exponent/2)
                       ; return ressqrt*ressqrt;                  }
  if (exponent%3 == 0) { NumT rescubrt = raiseTo(base,exponent/3)
                       ; return rescubrt*rescubrt*rescubrt;       }
  else return base * raiseTo(base, --exponent);
}
```

An example how many calculation this can save: suppose you want to raise a number to 19. That's 18 multiplications if you use the naïve loop-like approach. With this solution, what happens is

- 19 isn't divisible by either 2 or 3, so calculate *b* ⋅ *b*<sup>*e*-1</sup>, which is
- *b*<sup>18</sup>. Now 18 is divisible by 2, so we square *b*<sup>e/2</sup>, which is
- *b*<sup>9</sup>. Where 9 is divisible by 3, so we cube *b*<sup>e/3</sup>, which is
- *b*<sup>3</sup>. Where 3 is divisible by 3, so we cube *b*<sup>e/3</sup>, which is
- *b*<sup>1</sup>, which is b.

That was only 1+1+2+2 = 6 multiplications, 1/3 of the necessary amount for the loop-like approach! However, note that this doesn't necessarily mean the code will execute much faster, as the checking of factors also takes some time. In particular, the `%3` on `unsigned`s is probably not faster than multiplication on `int`s, so for `NumT==int` it's not really clever at all. But it *is* clever for the more expensive floating point types, `complex`, not to speak of linear algebra matrix types for which multiplication may be extremely expensive.

Comment: Why the c++ answer must use templates? C++ answer should use OO not OB

Comment: @Ulterior: C++ is fortunately _not_ a purely OO language. It allows you to use OO when appropriate, by there is absolutely no reason to do this here. A template, on the other hand, is straightforward, produces maximally fast compiled programs, and is automatically as general as possible.

Comment: @Pubby: I was wondering about that, too. Probably supposed to mean OBfuscation, which however I think simple templates like this are only for Java programmers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, leftaroundabout. I'll just have to think about this piece of code you've written here. I'm just trying to understand it, I'm only a beginner at this language.

Comment: Umm, I'm pretty sure `%` is more expensive than multiplication for all types, if it's even defined, that is.  Plus you don't need it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `%2` on `unsigned` (my function never needs to do it on any other type, as this is the _exponent_) is most certainly not more expensive than any multiplication, as it's equivalent to the bitmask `&1U`, so that and the `==0` can be optimized to a single machine instruction by any optimizing compiler; pretty sure about that. The `%3`, as I noted, is not quite so trivial, but should still be reasonably fast. Also, it's rather seldom called at all (only three times in my example), though you can argue that the brances which avoid this are probably the most expensive thing in my code...

Comment: @leftaroundabout: `%2` is as you say, a bitwise and.  Still not cheaper than multiply, as `*2` is a bit-shift.  And `%3` is MUCH more expensive than `*3`, for integral types, and not even allowed for floating-point or complex types (your examples of when you thought it would be faster).  I do see what you mean about the difference in type between `exponent` and `base`, however, I think my solution has just as few multiplies of the `base` type, and no division of the exponent type.  And is tail recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here

```
if (exponent > 0)
    return 1;
else if (exponent = 0)
```

firstly, you've inverted the conditional (if the exponent is equal to zero, it should return), secondly, you are assigning and not comparing with the second `if`.

Comment: The line `int answer = (int) pow((double)base, raisingTo(base, (exponent - 1)));` is also broken.

Comment: `else if (exponent = 0)` is a very rude mistake!. Because it is assignment and the result of this operation is right hand side value in this case `0` so this else if section will never be executed. For comparison `==` should be used.

Comment: @Seagull: Soo? He mentioned that.

Comment: Thank you Seagull for pointing out my mistake. It was a simple typo, I should have written out "==" as it is the comparison operator after all. Anyways, thanks a lot for your answer Necrolis.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version with better complexity (`O(lg exponent)`, instead of `O(exponent)`), which is conceptually similar to leftroundabout's version.

```
int raisingTo(int base const, unsigned int const exponent, int scalar = 1)
{
    if (exponent == 0)
        return scalar;

    if (exponent & 1) scalar *= base;
    return raisingTo(base * base, exponent >> 1, scalar);
}
```

It also uses tail recursion, which generally leads to better optimized machine code.

Comment: Can normal C compilers really get much improvement out of tail recursion? Didn't know that, I thought C-- was invented mainly because they don't.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Several modern compilers do optimize tail recursion into iteration, which is a substantial savings, as well as averting potential stack overflow.  It's not required by the Standard however, so I'd the an iterative version of this improved-complexity algorithm, except the question *requires* recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaner explanation with O(log n) complexity

```
public int fastPower(int base , int power){

if ( power==0 )
  return 1 
else if(power %2 == 0 )
  return fastPower(base*base,power/2)
else
 return base * fastPower(base,power-1)
}
```

This algo works on following simple rules of exponent

```
base^0 = 1
base^power = base*base^(power-1)
base^(2*power) = (base^2)^power
```

Thus at each level, value of n is either half of what it was or it is little less than n . Thus the deppest the recursion will ever go is `1+log n` levels

Information [source](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~jacobson/061/recursion.html)