# Can someone explain this snippet of code? - C++

Tags: c++, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Recursion to raise a base to its exponent - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348933/using-recursion-to-raise-a-base-to-its-exponent-c)

```
int raisingTo(int base, unsigned int exponent)
{
   if (exponent == 0)
    return 1;
   else
    return base * raisingTo(base, exponent - 1);
}
```

I wrote this code for raising an exponent to its base value using values passed by value from the `main()`. This function uses recursion to do this. Can someone explain how it returns a value each time it calls itself? I need a detailed explanation of this code.

Comment: Did you try just doing it on paper?

Comment: @Bart writing code that works but you don't understand is not uncommon for new programmers

Comment: Does copying the code from a school assignment count as "wrote it"?

Comment: @SethCarnegie, you don't call copy'n'pasting (for instance, from the question referenced by talonmies) writing, do you?

Comment: And the explanation of how it works is explicitly given there as well...

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker No, but how would I have known he copied it? I don't automatically assume people are lying when they don't understand something they say they wrote (I've done it plenty of times).

Comment: I do understand my code. You have to understand it to even write it. With due respect, all I meant was I didn't 'fully' understand its complexity. Since I had an idea of how it worked and wanted to understand how it 'actually' works, I asked this question here expecting a detailed answer. But still, 'thank you' for your contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best illustrated by doing iterations manually (as suggested in the comments). Suppose we have `base = 2` and `exponent = 2`.

- During the first iteration the function returns `2 * (whatever function yields when called with the arguments 2 and (2 - 1), which is 1)`.
- The second iteration with the arguments 2 and 1 gets the result `2 * (whatever the next iteration with arguments 2 and 0 returns)`.
- The thrid iteration will also be the last one since the function is set to return 1 when exponent is 0.

Now we have the full chain 2 * 2 * 1, therefore the result of the calculation is 4.

Comment: @Malcolm.I understand it now. Thanks Malcolm.

Answer (score 4):

We use the equation: `x^n = x * x^(n-1)` which is true for all real numbers.

So that we use it to create recursive function. The bottom of recursion is when the exponent == 0.

For example `2^4 = 2 * 2^3`; `2^3 = 2 * 2^2`; `2^2 = 2 * 2^1`; `2^1 = 2 * 2^0` and `2^0 = 1`.

Comment: +1, you wrote the code the OP "wrote", so you get to the second level ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker.Thank you for your most enlightening comment. If you are willing to answer my question, please do. Thank you.