# pow for Integral Values

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, pow, clamp

I need a version of [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) for integers. I have 2 problems that I need to solve with `pow`:

1. If the result is larger than my integral type I need to clamp to `numeric_limits::max()`
2. I need to be able to deal with 41.99999 rounding up to 42, rather than down to 41

Does C++ provide me some kind of inline solution here, or am I stuck writing my own function:

```
template <typename T>
enable_if_t<is_integral_v<T>, T> mypow(const T base, unsigned int exp) {
    T result = exp == 0U ? base : 1;

    while(exp-- > 1U) {
        if(numeric_limits<T>::max() / result <= base) return numeric_limits<T>::max();
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) and truncate the result if needed?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah... if there was a way to guarantee **1** and **2** wouldn't be violated by that. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: You can use tail recursion and some numeric trickery to improve runtime performance.  Further, you can make this method constexpr.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348933/using-recursion-to-raise-a-base-to-its-exponent-c

Answer (score 3):

> Does C++ provide me some kind of inline solution here

No, there is no integer `pow` in the standard library.

> or am I stuck writing my own function

Yes, you get to write your own function. Note that your shown multiplication loop  may be slower than using `std::pow` to implement the function, especially since you also have a branch and division in the loop:

```
template<class I>
I int_pow_no_overflow(I base, I exp)
{
    double max = std::numeric_limits<I>::max();
    double result = std::round(std::pow(base, exp));
    return result >= max
        ? max
        : result;
}
```

For a more generic approach, you may want to consider underflow as well.

There are as well other, faster algorithms (see for example *Exponentiation by squaring*) for integer exponentiation than the linear one you showed, but I'm unsure whether it would be worth considering them unless you deal with arbitrary precision arithmetic, or an embedded system with no floating point unit.

Comment: If you have a better way to avoid the truncation and to clamp using `pow` I'm all ears. What I've got was the best I could come up with, and it is very expensive.

Comment: Why do you need the generic programming?

Comment: @JonathanMee as a clue, N^8 = N^4 * N^4 so you don't need to calculate N^4 twice.

Comment: @JonathanMee how about the one I added to the answer?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Hmmm... I see what you're saying, I could have a logrithmic reduction in my loop count if I could just figure out how to do this...

Comment: @user2079303 Probably is as good as we can do :/ We could inline too I suppose: `static_cast<int>(min<double>(numeric_limits<int>::max(), round(pow(base, exp))))`

Comment: Problem with wrapping `std::pow` is that it works with `double`, and (at least on some platforms) a `long long` has some values that cannot be precisely represented by a `double`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou good point. If `long long` is needed, I would write a specialization with explicit conversions to `long double` to use that overload of `std::pow`.

Comment: @klitos-kyriacou That's a very good point.  This could make a very interesting example as a recursive function.

Comment: @user2079303 `long double` isn't necessarily able to store `long long`, because on platforms other than x86 it's still mostly the same as `double`

Comment: It's actually certain that it can't.  not enough mantissa bits available.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc well, you could check numeric_limits whether there are enough significand digits to represent the target values. If you really need to support long longs on all platforms, then perhaps fall-back to purely integer based algorithm.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy not at all certain. 80-bit long doubles are very typical, and have just the appropriate number of mantissa bits to represent signed 64 bit integers.

Comment: MS still doesn't support anything longer than the 64 bit double.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy or rather: no longer supports :) They used to.

Answer (score 2):

Your code did not compile, you should if possible check your code compiles first, use your compiler, or check it on compiler explorer first.

Also, you forgot to take into account negative values.  That's a very important feature of integral powers.  Code below is for regular int type.  I'll let you explore how you could extend it for other integral types.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
enable_if_t< is_integral<T>::value, T> 
mypow(T base, unsigned int exp) 
{
    T result = T(1);
    bool sign = (base < 0);

    if (sign) base = -base;

    T temp = result;
    while(exp-- != 0) 
    {
        temp *= base;
        if (temp < result)
        {
            return (sign) ? numeric_limits<T>::min() 
                          : numeric_limits<T>::max();
        }
        result = temp;
    }
    return (sign && (exp & 1)) ? -result : result;
}

template <typename T>
enable_if_t< !is_integral<T>::value, int> 
mypow(const T& base, unsigned int exp) 
{
    T result = T(1);
    int i_base = int(floor(base + .5));
    bool sign = (i_base < 0);

    if (sign) i_base = -i_base;

    int temp = result;
    while(exp-- != 0) 
    {
        temp *= i_base;
        if (temp < result)
        {
            return (sign) ? numeric_limits<int>::min() : numeric_limits<int>::max();
        }
        result = temp;
    }
    return (sign && (exp & 1)) ? -result : result;
}
```

In real life, I would do this note the use of floor, even in the integral case.

```
  template<typename T>
   enable_if_t< is_integral<T>::value, T> 
   mypow(T x, unsigned int y) { return T(floor(pow(x, y) + .5)); }

   template<typename T>
   enable_if_t< !is_integral<T>::value, int> 
   mypow(T x, unsigned int y) { return int(floor(pow(floor(x + .5), y) + .5)); }
```

Comment: I only intended this as an example, but yeah, this is one more reason that I don't want to go with writing my own function :(

Comment: Using floating point pow will generally be faster on CPU that support floating point ops.  Some modern CPUs have a floating-point pow instruction.

Comment: @JonathanMee:  Maybe you should check this interesting discussion on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int

Comment: If `x` `is_integral`, then why are you doing `floor(x+.5)` rather than `double(x)`? are you worried about 64bit integers not representable as `double`? They screw your code anyway.

Comment: @Walter sorry, it's a typo in second function, which is for floating  points.  I'm rounding the value, since that was part of the original question.  Thanks for pointing this out..